# How do I check (and update) a movie list in a nested database based on given parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

This is an exercise using loops and conditions on nested arrays / objects. It's rather beginner so please no fancy techniques.

Given that database:

```
DB = [
        {
            genre:'thriller', 
            movies:[
                {
                    title:'the usual suspects', release_date:1999
                }
            ]},
            {
            genre:'commedy', 
            movies:[
                {
                    title:'pinapple express', release_date:2008
                }
            ]}
    ]
```

How would I check if a genre, e.g. "drama" is in that database and at it (with similar pattern if not or do nothing if already present?

**My function at this point is:**

```
var moviesDB = function (array, genre) {
    for (var i= 0; i < array.legnth; i++) { 
        if (DB[i].genre != genre) {
            DB.genre({genre: genre, movies: []});
        }
    }
}
```

How would I do that correctly for moviesDB(DB, "drama")?

Answer (score 0):

First you want to search your movie DB array for any elements that do not match the search genre, if no matches are found then create a new array with the new entry with new genre and empty movie array, return the new array.

I have written this as a pure function.

```js
const DB = [
  {
    genre: 'thriller', 
    movies: [
      {
        title: 'the usual suspects',
        release_date: '1999'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    genre: 'comedy', 
    movies: [
      {
        title: 'pineapple express',
        release_date: '2008'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const addMissingGenre = (movieArray, genre) => {
  if (movieArray.every(movieGenre => movieGenre.genre !== genre)) {
    // create new array and add new genre object, and return
    return [...movieArray, { genre, movies: [] }];
  }
  return movieArray; // return unmutated array
};

console.log(addMissingGenre(DB, 'thriller')); // not added
console.log(addMissingGenre(DB, 'drama')); // added
```